# Exploiting shellshock

Tags: exploit, known-vulnerabilities, shellshock, bash, vulnerability

On doing some digging on the shell shock vulnerability, I found that being able to run the exploit via a remote location depends on whether the attacker actually knows the exact cgi script which uses bash as an interpreter on the vulnerable system. Am I right in this understanding and does this actually limit the scope of this vulnerability?
Also, does the attacker have to enumerate pages on the vulnerable system to get at a vulnerable cgi script eventually or is there other known methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the exact cgi script which **uses bash as an interpreter**

"Using bash as an interpreter" **not** a precondition for the exploitation of the *family* of bash vulnerabilities called "shellshock" (the *many distinct parsing vulnerabilities* based on an environment variable with any name beginning with exactly the bytes `() {`).

All you need to exploit one of "shellshock" vuln is to run the bash program with one user-controlled value of an environment variable; a shell script with bash as a shell interpreter (`#!/bin/bash` or `#!/bin/sh` where `/bin/sh` is a link to `bash`) is one obvious way to run bash, but many others exist when `/bin/sh` is bash: many function calls which run an external program take a string command (not a path and an array of arguments); notably `system` and `popen` (unlike the `exec*` family of functions). These functions taking a string use the default shell (`/bin/sh`) to parse the command string, so the use of these functions makes the program vulnerable to bash vulnerabilities, unless the environment has been cleaned up from any user input.

So any C program using these functions is potentially vulnerable. And programs written in other programming languages with similar functions.

This is *a lot more* programs than just `/bin/bash` scripts.

Of course, a C program can `exec` an executable file that happens to be a shell script with a `/bin/bash` interpreter, too.

> exact cgi script which uses bash

Please note that a "cgi *script*" can actually be *any program with the CGI interface*; it does not need to be a "script" as in shell *script*. Often, CGI "scripts" are written in compiled languages, like C.

> Also, does the attacker have to enumerate pages on the vulnerable
>   system

Many CGI scripts are in well known, fixed, locations, on most installations.